# How to convert ObjectResult<int?> to IEnumerable<int?>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I do understand that code I wrote is wrong, so don't leave a comment that my code wrong. I know that.

*Something like*

```
ObjectResult<int?> obj = new ObjectResult<int?> as IEnumerable
```

I can't instantiate ObjcetResult, because it is protected class. And I can't change the access modifier.

Comment: Have you tried `obj.ToArray()`? `obj.ToList()`should do, too...

Answer (score 4):

First, to answer your question:

You can't directly convert an `ObjectResult<int?>` to `IEnumerable<int>`.  While `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, there isn't an inheritance relationship between `int?` and `int`.

That said, you can cast it directly to an `IEnumerable<int?>`:

```
(IEnumerable<int?>)objResult
```

If you want an `IEnumerable<int>`, you can do:

```
var result = objResult.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Second, `ObjectResult` isn't a "protected" class, it's an `abstract` class.  `ObjectResult<T>` is a `sealed` class.  Neither `abstract` nor `sealed` are  access modifiers.

Comment: Nice! You are correct about the class. The constructor of ObjectResult<T> is protected. *.ToList() or *.ToArray() doesn't work as well, its expecting ObjectResult.